# angular2 uncaught ReferenceError require is not defined "boot.ts"

Tags: typescript, angular

I followed the Angular2 Quick Start closely and cannot get it to work.

Any advice?

I get 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Followed by this against my boot.js file.
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Here is my code.
https://github.com/robertdunaway/katas-angular2/tree/master/temp/after/src/vs2015-TS

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: See if this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5999) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="../lib/angular2/bundles/upgrade.dev.js"></script>
```

Add to you index.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I gave that a try with no success.  Did it work for you or did you just recognize my problem?  Anyway, thanks for taking a stab at it.  If you think of anything else let me know.